# How to create Excel Controls (Combo boxes etc) using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm working on a project to create and email a spreadsheet that is created by an ASP.NET/Visual Basic web application.

The top of this spreadsheet is one large cell, in which sits a Drop Down List, two Text Boxes, a few Labels and a Checkbox.

How do I create and organise these controls using Visual Basic? The spreadsheet is being physically created and I can manipulate cells at the moment, but I do not know how to create those controls specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create these controls programmatically then this code should get you going,  Essentially add a control, position it and set those properties that you require.

```
Sub addControls()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 60
        .Rows(1).RowHeight = 150

        'label
        Set addedLbl = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1")
            With addedLbl
                .Left = 180
                .Top = 25
                .Width = 90
                .Object.BackColor = &HC0C0FF
                .Object.Caption = "A Coloured Label"
            End With

        'combobox
        Set addedCmbo = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Combobox.1")
            With addedCmbo
                .Left = 180
                .Top = 75
                .Width = 90
                .Height = 20
            End With

        'checkbox
        Set addedChkBox = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1")
            With addedChkBox
                .Left = 25
                .Top = 25
                .Width = 90
                .Height = 20
                .Object.Caption = "A Checkbox"
                .Object.SpecialEffect = 2
                .Object.Value = False
            End With

        'textbox
        Set addedTextBox = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.TextBox.1")
            With addedTextBox
                .Left = 25
                .Top = 75
                .Width = 90
                .Height = 50
                .Object.WordWrap = True
                .Object.MultiLine = True
                .Object.SpecialEffect = 1
                .Object.Text = "Some wrapped text in this raised textbox."
            End With

    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to add them manually then select the Developer Tab and in the Controls group select Insert.  You can then add controls to the worksheet.  I have used ActiveX controls.  Then right-click the control to list its Properties.

[image: Add Controls]

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that I wanted to add them programatically. This is great, I'll get started on this ASAP and mark it as the accepted answer if I can get it working. Thank you.